# How to make purely random generation of numbers in certain interval

Tags: java, random, generator

I have an generation method that generates numbers between 1 and 8. But the problem is that this method often generates the numbers 1-7 and almost never number 8. My question is that how to generate random numbers in certain interval but that all numbers appear approximately same times ?

EDIT:

my number generator

```
public int generateNumber() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(8 - 1) + 1;

}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with Java's built-in random generator(s), or wish to repair your own?  If the latter, you'd need to show what your generator looks like.

Comment: I have problem with generators in general and also with mine. Here is my code

Comment: Besides the fact that your range was wrong you should not be calling `Random r = new Random();` over and over. Call it once and reuse it. You may discover calling it each time the way you are may yield less than random results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random generator generates an "uniformly distributed int value between **0 (inclusive)** and the **specified value (exclusive)**" Please refer to the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

You can do:

```
random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

And it should be fine.

Alternatively,

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= NUMBER_OF_INTEGERS_YOU_WANT; idx++){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(8)+1; 
  CODE_HERE
 }
```

Comment: Your code will return integers between 0 and 8 (inclusive). OP wants between 1 and 8 (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

"almost never number 8": If that generator ever generates 8 there is something wrong.

The nextInt gives a number between 0 and 6 (borders inclusive) and adding one gives the interval [1,7].

To get numbers in [1,8] you can use

```
r.nextInt(8) + 1
```

Comment: that's why it caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
return r.nextInt(8) + 1;
```

Which will return values from 1 to 8. So it starts with 0 and generated number max uptil n-1 i.e. 7 as per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

In your case, you have `r.nextInt(8 - 1)` which evaluates to `r.nextInt(7)` so it would generate numbers from 0 -6 and on top of that you are adding 1 to number from above api, so your range is 1-7 and not 1-8.